# Is using __import__('module_name') an antipattern in Python?

Tags: design-patterns, python, anti-patterns, plugin-architecture

I'm currently refactoring a Python 2 project which includes the ability to add or remove plugins, which are Python modules implementing a given API.

The main app accesses add/remove/update hooks in plugins by calling e.g. `__import__('plugin_name').hook_add()` after pulling plugin names from a database, but this seems like a hacky approach. Having said that, I don't know of better ways to programatically access plugins.

Is this considered an antipattern in Python?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with `__import__`. You could possibly use the `importlib` module instead, but it isn't necessarily a better alternative. If you think it is a hacky approach, maybe you can try to design a better solution and see if it is clearer and easier to understand than the current code.

Answer (score 3):

> ## Is using `__import__('module_name')` an antipattern in Python?

The api for `__import__` is somewhat misleading. I personally would prefer to avoid it where possible.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) for Python 3 state:

> Direct use of `__import__()` is also discouraged in favor of `importlib.import_module()`.

Here's the API for `__import__`:

```
mod = __import__(
    module, # string of dotted name
    globals=None, # only needed to do relative import
    locals=None, # implementation ignores this
    fromlist=()) # fromlist just needs to be non-empty... :(
    level=0 # relative import, not going into this part
    )
```

If fromlist is empty, you import the module, but get returned the root package like this, so you have to do the dotted lookup to get back to it:

```
>>> foo = __import__('foo.bar.baz')
>>> foo.bar.baz
<module 'foo.bar.baz' from /.../foo/bar/baz.py>
```

This is the same as

```
>>> import foo.bar.baz
>>> foo.bar.baz
<module 'foo.bar.baz' from /.../foo/bar/baz.py>
```

If you just want the module, you need fromlist to be non-empty:

```
>>> baz = __import__('foo.bar.baz', fromlist=[None])
>>> baz
<module 'foo.bar.baz' from /.../foo/bar/baz.py>
```

Which is the same as

```
>>> from foo.bar import baz
>>> baz
<module 'foo.bar.baz' from /.../foo/bar/baz.py>

>>> baz is foo.bar.baz
True
```

### Use `importlib.import_module` instead:

Here's the usage for [import_module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html):

```
>>> from importlib import import_module
>>> baz = import_module('foo.bar.baz')
```

That's much nicer.